# How to get Identity Server 4's access_token in ASP Net 4.7 MVC Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, identityserver4

I have some issues getting the access_token of the Identity Server 4 in my ASP Net 4.7.2 client application to call an API.

In ASP .Net Core client, I can get the access_token like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CallApi()
    {
        var accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");

        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
        var content = await client.GetStringAsync("http://localhost:5001/identity");

        ViewBag.Json = JArray.Parse(content).ToString();
        return View("Json");
    }
```

Just the simple:

```
var accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
```

But how can I get the access_token in my ASP Net 4.x client?

My Startup code looks like this:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var authority = JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "Cookies",
            CookieName = "CustomIdentityCookie"
        });

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            //AuthenticationType = "oidc",              
            Authority = "http://localhost:5000",
            RedirectUri = "http://localhost:57319/signin-oidc",
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = "http://localhost:57319/signout-callback-oidc",
            ClientId = "mvc472",
            ClientSecret = "secret",
            ResponseType = "code id_token",
            Scope = "api01 openid profile offline_access",

            // for debug
            RequireHttpsMetadata = false,

            UseTokenLifetime = false,
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies"
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this using an OWIN pipeline and the JWT middleware?

Comment: https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core

Comment: @IainMNorman Yes it is

Comment: Your snippet for the ASP.NET Core client above can only be done post-authentication (after you've received the access token). So are you asking how you can retrieve the access token from within the OWIN client post-authentication?

Comment: @Randy Yes, can't get the access token. Now I'm a bit further and this part worked, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I got a solution. Hope anybody can tell me if this solution is ok.
I used the workaround from the IdentityServer3 like this: [IdentityServer 3 Mvc Client](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/blob/master/source/Clients/MVC%20OWIN%20Client%20(Hybrid)/Startup.cs)
I edited the depricated methods and updated to Identity Server 4.

It worked, except the logout: I get not redirected to the MVC App after logout from Identity Server. I get a 404 Error, can't find the /signout-callback-oidc route.

Here the new Startup class:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        //var authority = JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "Cookies"
        });

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "oidc",                
            Authority = "http://localhost:5000",
            RedirectUri = "http://localhost:57319/signin-oidc",
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = "http://localhost:57319/signout-callback-oidc",
            ClientId = "mvc472",
            ClientSecret = "secret",
            ResponseType = "code id_token",
            Scope = "api01 openid profile offline_access",

            // for debug
            RequireHttpsMetadata = false,

            UseTokenLifetime = false,
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",

            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                AuthorizationCodeReceived = async n =>
                    {
                        var client = new HttpClient();
                        DiscoveryResponse disco = await client.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync("http://localhost:5000");

                        var tokenResponse = await client.RequestAuthorizationCodeTokenAsync(new AuthorizationCodeTokenRequest
                        {
                            Address = disco.TokenEndpoint,
                            RedirectUri = "http://localhost:57319/signin-oidc",                             
                            ClientId = "mvc472",
                            ClientSecret = "secret",
                            Code = n.Code
                        });

                        var userInfoResponse = await client.GetUserInfoAsync(new UserInfoRequest
                        {
                            Address = disco.UserInfoEndpoint,
                            Token = tokenResponse.AccessToken
                        });

                        var id = new ClaimsIdentity(n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AuthenticationType);
                        id.AddClaims(userInfoResponse.Claims);

                        id.AddClaim(new Claim("access_token", tokenResponse.AccessToken));
                        id.AddClaim(new Claim("expires_at", DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(tokenResponse.ExpiresIn).ToLocalTime().ToString()));
                        id.AddClaim(new Claim("refresh_token", tokenResponse.RefreshToken));
                        id.AddClaim(new Claim("id_token", tokenResponse.IdentityToken));
                        id.AddClaim(new Claim("sid", n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst("sid").Value));

                        n.AuthenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(
                            new ClaimsIdentity(id.Claims, n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AuthenticationType, "name", "role"),
                            n.AuthenticationTicket.Properties
                            );

                    },

                // noch nicht getestet
                RedirectToIdentityProvider = n =>
                {
                    // if signing out, add the id_token_hint
                    if (n.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.Logout)
                    {
                        var idTokenHint = n.OwinContext.Authentication.User.FindFirst("id_token");

                        if (idTokenHint != null)
                        {
                            n.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = idTokenHint.Value;
                        }

                    }

                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            }



        });
    }
}
```